# Better to convert IntelliJ project to Gradle or to use Android Studio import project?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

If you open an IntelliJ project in Android Studio, there is a warning that you should migrate to Gradle and it sends you to [this link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-intellij-projects). This process seems a bit strange and complicating since the process is not well explained (it's more for experienced programmers who know how Gradle project looks like).

There is also a feature in Android Studio to import IntelliJ IDEA project. I did it with my project and it imported everything (except empty Proguard file), compiled well and all seems to work fine.

However, is this a valid process too - can I safely import future IDEA's project using import feature rather than the solution suggested by Android Studio?

Are there hidden dangers using this method? The least I would like it to continue coding newly imported Gradle-based project and at some point realize that the project is corrupted.

Comment: Sandalone: Just like you I imported an android project built by InteiJ Idea to android studio. but still android studio warns me about migrating to grade build system. There is any trick there that you did?

Comment: @VahidGhadiri In one project I left it as old project type and in another I converted it to Gradle. If you are used to IntelliJ-type project, maybe you should leave it as is. You can work in Android Studio with such project seamlessly.

Comment: @Suandalone: But I urgently need to convert it to android studio, even if I have to do it manually. But I don't know how I can do that. Could you please just give me a hint about that?

Comment: @VahidGhadiri I simply let Android Studio convert it and it was all fine here. I suggest you go error by error and narrow down issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fine. The projects it imports have their Gradle files properly set up, and if it works okay after import, there's nothing about the process by which it created that should make it stop working in the future. I think the link in that warning is just out of date.

Comment: Thanks. I am using the latest Android  Studio so you maybe give someone a hint to update the link ;).